# Redis key restrictions with scan

Tags: redis

I have some code that stores, in redis, a flag of whether a user is active, under a unique key per user.

```
class RedisProfileActiveRepo implements ProfileActiveRepo
{
    /** @var Redis  */
    private $redis;

    public function __construct(Redis $redis)
    {
        $this->redis = $redis;
    }

    public function markProfileIsActive(int $profile_id)
    {
        $keyname = ProfileIsActiveKey::getAbsoluteKeyName($profile_id);

        // Set the user specific key for 10 minutes
        $result = $this->redis->setex($keyname, 10 * 60, 'foobar');
    }

    public function getNumberOfActiveProfiles()
    {
        $count = 0;
        $pattern = ProfileIsActiveKey::getWildcardKeyName();
        $iterator = null;

        while (($keys = $this->redis->scan($iterator, $pattern)) !== false) {
            $count += count($keys);
        }

        return $count;
    }
}
```

When I generate the keys from this code:

```
namespace ProjectName;

class ProfileIsActive
{
    public static function getAbsoluteKeyName(int $profile_id) : string
    {
        return __CLASS__ . '_' . $profile_id;
    }

    public static function getWildcardKeyName() : string
    {
        return __CLASS__ . '_*';
    }
}
```

Which results in the keys looking like `ProjectName\ProfileIsActive_1234` the scan command in Redis fails to match any keys.

When I replace the slashes with underscores:

```
class ProfileIsActive
{
    public static function getAbsoluteKeyName(int $profile_id) : string
    {
        return str_replace('\\', '', __CLASS__) . '_' . $profile_id;
    }

    public static function getWildcardKeyName() : string
    {
        return str_replace('\\', '', __CLASS__) . '_*';
    }
}
```

The code works as expected.

My question is - why is doing a scan with a slash in the keyname failing to behave as expected, and are there any other characters that should be avoided in keynames to avoid similar problems?

Comment: Hey, did you read my response ?

Comment: yes - sorry, managed to get food poisoning so haven't had chance to check that it's correct yet.

Comment: My bad. I wish you get better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically latest Redis autoescapes backslashes when you set keys at `redis-cli`:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set this\test 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> keys this*
1) "this\\test"
```

Issue a `MONITOR` command in `redis-cli` before you run your php client code, and watch for `SCAN` commands. If your collection is big enough and your `count` parameter is absent or low enough you might not get the record:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 0 match this*
1) "73728"
2) (empty list or set)

127.0.0.1:6379> scan 0 match this* count 10000
1) "87704"
2) 1) "this\\test"
```

Comment: Every client seems to be auto-escaping keys with slashes. This is mildly surprising behaviour.

Comment: I forgot to say - you could improve you answer by saying "redis commands that are wildcard aware, don't escape backslashes. Commands that aren't wildcard aware _do_ escape backslashes." as that is what was confusing me.

Comment: Hi! You're right about that, both `keys` and `scan` commands don't return anything searching for `this\test`.